# Issue parsing JSX with JEST framework

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I would like to test a js file with JEST which includes some functions that return jsx.

**The error is triggered on the return statement of this function:**

```
export const my_func = (entries) => {
    return entries.map(entry => <div value={entry}> {entry} </div>)
}
```

**Im getting the following error:**

```
 SyntaxError: /routes/my-app/helper-functions.js: Unexpected token (304:45)

 at Parser.raise (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:6344:17)
      at Parser.unexpected (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:7659:16)
      at Parser.parseExprAtom (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:8828:20)
      at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:8413:23)
      at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:8393:21)
      at Parser.parseExprOps (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:8280:23)
      at Parser.parseMaybeConditional (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:8253:23)
      at Parser.parseMaybeAssign (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:8200:21)
      at Parser.parseFunctionBody (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9390:24)
      at Parser.parseArrowExpression (node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9349:10)
```

**Ive set up babel configuration in - babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        targets: {
          node: 'current',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

**Inside of my package.json I have:**

```
"scripts":{
    "test":"jest"
}
```

**Test code and import statement below:**

```
import {sum} from '../routes/my-app/helper-functions';

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
    expect(sum(1,2)).toBe(3);
});
```

Im running my tests using the **`yarn test`** command in a terminal.

**What am i missing configuration-wise to get this file to import properly?**

Comment: `{entry}/div>` should be `{entry}</div>`

Comment: Thanks, that part was a typo (my actual code is correct)

Comment: how error message itself looks like? stacktrace does not add details on rootcause

Comment: Don't you need to add `@babel/preset-react` as well?

Comment: can you also post your test code and the import statement ?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli updated to include code and import

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I've tried to append that to the first list in presets, unfortunately same result. Can you clarify where that line should go?

Comment: @DannyMoshe `presets: [ ['@babel/preset-env', {...}] , '@babel/preset-react']` should work

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I've added that to the setup yet same issue persists